# How to enforce a resource as a function argument (type declaration)

Tags: php, type-hinting

I'd like to make sure that a function only accepts a `resource` as a parameter.

For any other type, I would just write something similar to

```
function my_function(string $my_string) { }
```

and PHP will throw a TypeError whenever I pass anything other than a string to it. Nice.

The [PHP documentation on the subject](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration), does not list the `resource` as a type declaration candidate.

I know I can use something like

```
function my_function($resource) {
    if (!is_resource($resource)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('resource expected, ' .
            gettype($resource) . ' given');
    }
    // do stuff that expects the resource
}
```

However, this feels wrong. In my opinion, type declaration / hinting exists for good reasons and I don't understand why a `resource` could not be used (I can understand why a `trait` would not be allowed).

(On a side note, [a solution](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php#83442) for the old behavior where not even scalar types weren't allowed also implements checking for resources. So, I'm not the only one looking for it...)

*There is one argument I could think of why a `resource` can not be declared: being a `resource` still can mean a lot of things since it could be any kind of resource. However, this argument would also hold for the `array`, a type that **can** be declared!*

Is the code above the best way to proceed? Are there other ways? Or am I on the wrong track? Am I missing some point?

I am *not* looking for the PHPDoc-solution. While that would aid development, it won't catch wrong arguments at run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP a resource is not similar to for instance a file descriptor in C. There is no single interface. For instance both xml_parser_create and fopen return resources but have distinct interfaces. So forcing a function argument to be of type resource. Does not really say much.

Your best option is properly to create the interface you need for your class and create a default wrapper class implementing this interface for the resource functionality in question. The will give users of your class the most freedom.

Comment: Interesting work-around. Although it is not fundamentally solving the problem, it does hide the ugly code to do the actual checking of the resource. On your first paragraph, this does not seem in line with the fact that the `is_resource` function _does_ exist? (Although that func does not actually do strict typing)

Comment: is_resource only checks that a variable is of type resource. It does not check whether you are suppose to use it with fwrite or xml_parse or yet another procedural set of functions using the resource type.

Comment: That's what I meant with my comment in italics in de Q. This is IMHO exactly the same issue with a type declaration with an `array`: one can not check what is _inside_ the array, only that it is some array. I do not see why a resource cannot be declared if an array can...

Comment: Except that an array still has a defined set of functions that can be used, resources don't.

Comment: After giving it some thought, also a `resource` has a defined set of functions: besides `is_resource`, there is `get_resource_type` which generates an error if the argument is not a `resource`. But, you have my 'answered' vote, until a better answer occurs...